# Nginx not responding

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  10000;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log  off;

    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  30;
    keepalive_requests  100000;

    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1 SSLv3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL:!EDH; 
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_min_length 10240;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    # http server
    server {
        listen   80;
        listen   [::]:80;

        server_name www.mywebsite.net;

        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    } # end http server

    # https server
    server {
        listen 443 default ssl;
        server_name www.mywebsite.net;
        ssl_certificate      mywebsite.net.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  www.mywebsite.net.key;

        ## Parameterization using hostname of access and log filenames.
        access_log logs/localhost_access.log;
        error_log logs/localhost_error.log;

        ## Root and index files.
        root html;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        ## If no favicon exists return a 204 (no content error).
        location = /favicon.ico {
            try_files $uri =204;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        ## Don't log robots.txt requests.
        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }
        ## Try the requested URI as files before handling it to PHP.
        location / {

            ## Regular PHP processing.
            location ~ \.php$ {
                root           html;
                try_files  $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

            ## Static files are served directly.
            location ~* \.(?:css|gif|htc|ico|js|jpe?g|png|swf)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
                ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
                ## fell swoop.
                tcp_nodelay off;
                ## Set the OS file cache.
                open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=120s;
                open_file_cache_valid 45s;
                open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
                open_file_cache_errors off;
            }

            error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                root   html;
            }

            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one

            location ~ /\.ht {
                deny  all;
            }

            ## Keep a tab on the 'big' static files.
            location ~* ^.+\.(?:ogg|pdf|pptx?)$ {
                expires 30d;
                ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
                ## fell swoop.
                tcp_nodelay off;
            }
        } # / location
    } # end https server
}
```

I am running 1.5.2 on my Windows Server 2012, I've heard that it's bad to have a high worker processes value so I've decreased it to 1, still the same issue as with 10 workers, the website responds great but suddenly stops responding after 6-10 hours.

All the needed ports are open and the server is running great.

Comment: What else is happening at the same time?  What makes you think that it's nginx that's failing?  What do the logs show?  What application are you running nginx on top of?

Comment: Running nginx with mariadb, php and fastcgi, all the logs are empty.

Comment: The nginx logs are empty after it "stops responding?"  What about system logs leading up to the web server stall?  What does netstat show for open ports?

Comment: Also, 'keepalive_requests  100000;' set this so something more reasonable. As well as 'worker_connections  10000;' -- unless your application can handle that many connections (it can't), set it to something reasonable...at the very least $application_memory_use_minimum / $total_available_user_space_memory

Comment: @tristan I have now set `worker_connections  2000;` and `keepalive_requests  5000;` on a 8gig machine, when I check the error logs for nginx, mariadb or PHP they are all empty since the last time I've emptied them (logging is working). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @tristan Still doesn't work, pretty pissed...

Comment: This isn't free tech support.  Can you tcpdump when you think nginx is stalled to see if connections are coming from upstream?

Comment: @tristan Didn't mean to give the impression as if someone owes me anything, just pretty pissed at the damn thing, have been trying to fix this the past 3 days, php-cgi.exe seems to crash with no reason whatsoever and doesn't leave anything with the logs, I start it properly.